# Web scraping video information from youtube using python

Tags: python, web, youtube, web-crawler

I want to extract video information(like title, viewer's counts) of a certain Youtube video using python, just as I did web scraping on other websites. But for some reason, either it returns nothing or provides tags only for recommended videos on the side instead of "the main video" of the URL

I tried the same codes that I used for web-scraping on other websites as below. Apparently it doesn't work on Youtube. What should I do if I want to get video information based on a youtube URL?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url ='https://www.youtube.com/watch?'
search_string = 'v=I41aLSzLI50'
url = base_url + search_string
supers=requests.get(url).content    
data = BeautifulSoup(supers,'html.parser')
videos =data.find_all('a', class_= 'content-link spf-link yt-uix-sessionlink spf-link')
for video in videos:
    print(video.find('span', class_='title').get_text())
```

Comment: first you should check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add content - BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript. You could also print content from `requests` to see what you get. Maybe you get something different then you can get in web browser. It can send Captcha or warning message, etc.

Comment: try using the `youtube_dl` module

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the youtube api? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Comment: no specific reason, just that I'm that beginner only knowing BeautifulSoup. I guess the reason why I couldn't see HTML content of the main video was the page uses JavaScript. Let me try youtube_dl and youtube api as you guys suggested.Big thanks!

Comment: but another question is why I couldn't see any from the code just because it's in Javascript?

Comment: @SungYeonPark: because you parse the HTML that the server provides you. The fact that JavaScript later alters the DOM is not taken into account, since, well, the JavaScript does not run automagically.

Answer (score 2):

I looked up a page on YouTube, and it seems that the you are looking for is not in the original source (at least not where you are expecting it). There are scripts that create the content when your browser renders the page. Based on my experience, you have a few options.

1. Use one of the APIs the commenters suggested. I am not very familiar with these, but it might same you some time and effort. Web scraping can be problematic because of changes in page format (scripts may need to be updated).
2. If you insist on web scraping, you can use an automated browser. I used to use Selenium on a regular basis and it should work for your purposes. This will allow you to work with content generated by scripts.
3. I looked at the page source, and the information you are looking for appears to be contained within some  tags, but parsing this will be a pain.